# different writing times for images in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I wrote a simple code to evaluate the writing time of different image formats in opencv ...

```
void main()
{
#define SIZE 1024 ;//2048,4096 ... 
  cv::Mat image = cv::Mat(Size,Size,CV_8UC3,cv::Scalar(255));

  for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++)
    {
      double t1 = cv::getTickCount();
      QString Address = "Data/" + QString::number(i) + ".bmp";
      cv::imwrite(Address.toUtf8().constData(),image);
      t1 = (cv::getTickCount()-t1)*1000/cv::getTickFrequency();
      qDebug()<<"Writing time is: "<<t1<<"\n";
      cv::waitKey(100);
    }
}
```

the output for 2048*2048 was:

11.7852  ms  -- 11.7595  ms  -- 11.765  ms  -- 11.5781  ms  -- 11.5957  ms  -- 11.4912  ms
248.912  ms  -- 263.184  ms  -- 11.8521  ms  -- 221.688  ms

when I run this code for 4096*4096 the output is:

43.3954  ms  -- 310.977  ms
1061.97  ms  -- 624.651  ms
1114.33  ms  -- 563.779  ms
1055.95  ms  -- 1115.99  ms
345  ms      -- 1135.97  ms

as you can see the writing time differs from one image to another ... this difference is very enormous and I don't know why the writing time is not approximately the same for all the images.

I am writing my code in linux ubuntu 12.04 under qt environment .. My PC Spec is Core-i7 sandybridge Harddisk 5400rpm  and 8 gigabytes internal ram

I tried my code for ".jpg" format and the output was:

Writing time is:
105.14  ms
105.797  ms
101.163  ms
103.342  ms
105.057  ms
100.315  ms
105.821  ms
104.271  ms
102.357  ms
102.396  ms

as you can see there is no any substantial difference in writing time in .jpg format but for .bmp an abrupt change of writing time happens ...

is it because of hard drive access time ? if so , why this doesn't happen in .jpg format ?

Thanks.

Comment: `JPG` is a compressed image type, while `BMP` is not. Try to check out the images you saved, all jpg images should be roughly in same size, not for bmp images.

Comment: I had a similar problem some time ago, working on a debian system, writing times were constant in the beginning but were very strongly increased at some random time (for some short duration and small afterwards again) so that some frames were dropped during live writing to disk. I still don't know exactly why that happened, but might be a caching/defragmenting thing the OS did. I couldnt solve the problem directly but I added a  queue to write the images by a separate thread to disk. Your problem might be the disk writing speed though, you should check image size and disk speed!

Comment: The variability in the time will likely increase with the size of the file you are writing to disk because of context switching etc. Since JPEG is compressed whereas BMP is not, the time to write JPEGs to disk is likely to be substantially shorter than BMP, hence the variance in the write time should also be smaller. To test this, try to write JPEGs which are larger, preferably taking up the same space as your BMPs. Then the timings should start to match.

Comment: @Micka Thanks for your comment ... But I need to know why there's this much variance in writing images into hard disk in bmp format but not  .jpeg ones ....

Comment: @lightalchemist Dear chemist !, I tested your solution and the time was constant for all the jpeg images ...( as you can see in the outputs , the writing time variance in .jpeg images is not comparable to .bmp ones)